# How can I store an Environment.SpecialFolder path as a string and then parse it back to Environment.SpecialFolder?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, parsing

I am developing a WinForms application that stores the user's settings in a text file. I reference this save file when the user updates their settings as well as when the program starts up. Everything is working with the `StreamWriters` and `StreamReaders`, except that when I write data to the text file, it is automatically converted to a string since .txt files don't hold variable types.

One of the settings is the default directory to open files from, and the `OpenFileDialog` dialog only accepts `Environment.SpecialFolder` file paths. I'm having trouble parsing the string to a usable `Environment.SpecialFolder`. I realize I could check the value using the `string.Contains(string s)` method but I would like to know if there is a simpler way first.

Answer (score 3):

`SpecialFolder` is an enumeration; to parse enumeration values, use `Enum.Parse(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder), "ValueGoesHere")`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've written your own classes to manage user settings in a text file. You might want to consider using the [application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e.aspx) classes to do that for you. I think they handle enumerations for you, but I'm not sure.